# Gmail images with basic HTTP auth

Tags: image, email, url, gmail, basic-authentication

so I tried to add login:password@ in front of image url, it works fine on most of places, but gmail adds something like this in front of a link

[https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/PbD7QaU96Qnoi2YMXozkcMQH3ux61AQVaEF-FA-UCXF67zOIdDDDMgbHbddkreo8OVe18IfhOhK4xSXtkeyI6umvOcBIcN0kCo5acqgwDr6iy05q7mXorXkxAXFLBK0mI_9pWwPJPOvY080iA6K01BRjtpU7rgwPUXguTu2RCqHp8Kzz9Cl2-ndSigGyU-Q8Lx5PMSiMoJJvdp0iuVoJzEnq=s0-d-e1-ft#{{our](https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/PbD7QaU96Qnoi2YMXozkcMQH3ux61AQVaEF-FA-UCXF67zOIdDDDMgbHbddkreo8OVe18IfhOhK4xSXtkeyI6umvOcBIcN0kCo5acqgwDr6iy05q7mXorXkxAXFLBK0mI_9pWwPJPOvY080iA6K01BRjtpU7rgwPUXguTu2RCqHp8Kzz9Cl2-ndSigGyU-Q8Lx5PMSiMoJJvdp0iuVoJzEnq=s0-d-e1-ft#%7B%7Bour) url here}}

what causes issues, of not having this images loaded.

Any workaround guys?

Answer (score 0):

```
var e=new RegExp("^https://[a-zA-Z0-9]+.googleusercontent.com/proxy/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+[=][a-zA-Z0-9-+]+#");
var t=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var n=0; n<t.length;n++) {
t[n].src=t[n].src.replace(e,"")
}
```